# Modify ListView ItemTemplate at runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, grid, itemtemplate

I have a ListView:

```
           <ListView>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Height="90" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Gray">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.2*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="changeThis" Width="140"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="45"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                ...
                            </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
           </ListView>
```

When the screen orientation changes to Portrait I would like the 3rd (140px wide) column to disappear, so the other columns stay properly visible. I use VisualStateManager to manage the orientation change, but I get an exception if I try to change the "changeThis" ColumnDefinition to 0. And strangely I cannot access "changeThis" ColumnDefinition from the code behind. It is a Windows Store App.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the x:Name is local to the item template and cannot be accessed from outside.

Possible Solutions are:
1: Bind the Width to a Property.
    {Binding DataContext.MyColumnWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}

2: Use an ItemTemplateSelector with different Templates for Orientations.